# Account is not granted with modify permission on folder in linux

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, amazon-web-services, nopcommerce

I have a dot net core nopcommerce application running on ec2-linux machine, i am in root mode and i am getting this error.

```
The 'ip-10-8-2-66\root' account is not granted with Modify permission on folder '/home/ec2-user/dependent-linux-x64/bin'. Please configure these permissions

The 'ip-10-8-2-66\root' account is not granted with Modify permission on folder '/home/ec2-user/dependent-linux-x64/logs'. Please configure these permissions.
```

The dependent-linux-x64 is the nopcommerce published in framework dependent with linux-x64. 
I am getting the localhost:5000/install page so that means the application is running. I also have mysql installed for database connection string but i am not able to solve the above issue. 
i have used the following command 
`chmod +x dependent-linux-x64` in root mode but still the above issue pertains.

Comment: Pls run ```ls -l /home/ec3-user/dependent-linux-x64``` and lets see the users and their permissions

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as you.  I ran the linux command suggested by George Udosen, and found I had all read and write privileges, however I didn't have a bin folder.  I created a `~/bin` directory and one of my error messages went away, I then created a `~/logs` directory and the error stopped.

my suggestion

```
mkdir /home/ec2-user/dependent-linux-x64/bin
mkdir /home/ec2-user/dependent-linux-x64/logs
```